# what condition is necessary that three term of a arithmetic sequence make a geometric sequence?

Tags: calculus

Let $a_m,a_n,a_t$ be Three terms of an arithmetic sequence.When we have $a_n^2=a_m\times a_t$.

Comment: can we also set $$a_1,a_2=a_1+d,a_3=1+2d$$?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices that you solve $$\dfrac{a_t}{a_n}=\dfrac{a_n}{a_m}$$ or 
$$\dfrac{a_1+(t-1)d}{a_1+(n-1)d}=\dfrac{a_1+(n-1)d}{a_1+(m-1)d}$$ find relation between $a,d$ then put in $$Q=\dfrac{a_t}{a_n}=\dfrac{a_n}{a_m}$$ 
foe example :
   suppose $a_2,a_4,a_8$ of an arithmetic ,are geometric 
  so 
$$\dfrac{a_t}{a_n}=\dfrac{a_n}{a_m}=\\
\dfrac{a_1+7d}{a_1+3d}=\dfrac{a_1+3d}{a_1+d}$$ 
$$a_1^2+7d^2+8da_1=a_1^2+9d^2+6da_1\\2da_1=2d^2 \\d\neq 0 \to\\a_1=d\\$$  so $$Q=\dfrac{a_1+7d}{a_1+3d}=\dfrac{d+7d}{d+3d}=2$$ 
like this $$2,\underbrace{4}_{a_2},6,\underbrace{8}_{a_4},10,12,14,\underbrace{16}_{a_8},18$$

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: this assumes the whole sequence is both arithmetic and geometric (actually, assumes $a_n, a_m, a_t$ are part of a geometric sequence where $a_n$ is in the n-th position and so

---

$a_m = a_n + (m - n)d, a_t = a_n + (t - n)d \implies a_m \cdot a_t = a_n^2 + (t + m - 2n)da_n + (m - n)(t - n)d^2$

But then $a_n^2 = a_ma_t \iff a_0^2 \cdot r^{2n} = a_0r^m \cdot a_0r^t \iff 2n = m + t$ or $r \in \{0, 1\}$, which are rather trivial cases

And, again, $a_n^2 = a_ma_t \iff (t + m - 2n)da_n + (m - n)(t - n)d^2 = 0 \iff (m-n)(t-n)d^2 = 0 \iff m = n \lor t = n \lor d=0$

In sum:

- if $a_n = 0$ then either $a_m = 0 \lor a_t = 0 \implies d = 0 \implies a_n = a_m = a_t = 0$
- if $a_n \ne 0 \implies a_m = a_t = a_n \implies d= 0$

So it must be a constant sequence.

Comment: This Terms 5,10,20 make a Geometric Sequence.but they can be any terms of a arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @user402083 Yeah, fleablood understood it the same way I did, it seems. Edited for disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

The question has changed since I answered.

If $a_m, a_n, a_t$ are three, not necessarily sequential, terms of an arithmetic non-constant sequence, and wolog $m < n < t$ so $a_m = a; a_n = a + kd; a_t = a+ jd; k = n-m; j = t -m$.  If these form a geometric sequence, then, as arithmetic and geometric sequences are monotonic:

$a+kd = a*r$

$a+jd = a*r^2$

for some $r > 0; r \ne 1$.

Presumable $a \ne 0$ (the only geometric sequence with a zero term is the constant zero sequence).

So $r = \frac {a*r^2}{a*r} = \frac {a + jd}{a+kd}$ and $r = \frac {a*r}{r}= \frac{a+kd}{a}$.  So $\frac {a + jd}{a+kd} = \frac{a+kd}{a}$

or $a(a+ jd) = (a+kd)^2$

$ajd = 2akd + k^2d^2$

$aj = 2ak + k^2d$

$j = 2k + \frac {k^2d}a$ which requires $k^2d$ being a integer multiple of $a$.  If $a$ and $d$ are both rational or $a = q*x; b= r*x$ for the same irrational $x$ and rational $q,r$ we can find such terms.

Ex. If $S_n = \{2.3 + .7n|n \in \mathbb N\}$ and we want $8.6$ to the first term a geometric sequence, we require $\frac {k^2*.7}{8.6}= \frac {k^2*7}{86}$ to be an integer.  Let $k = 86$ then $k^2*.7/8.6 = 602$ then $j = 2*86 + 86*7 = 774$.

So $s_9, s_{95}, s_{783}$ which are

$8.6, 8.6 + 86*.7 = 68.8, 8.6 + 774*.7 = 550.4$ are first three terms of $T_n = \{8.6 *r^n| n \in \mathbb N; r = \frac {68.8}{8.6}=8\}$

Check?  $8.6*8^2= 500.4$

There are two more stipulations.  One $a_n, a_m, a_t$ most all be positive or all be negative.  So $j = 2k + \frac {k^2d}a$ condition will be solvable if $a > 0; d > 0$ or $a < 0; d< 0$.  But for $\frac da < 0$, if $k = n - m > 0$ we may have $j t-m < 0 t< m$, which if $t < 0$ would be a term not in the series.

In my example if $S_n = \{10 - .7*k| k \ge 0\}$ then I won't be able to find a geometric series beginning with $8.6$.  $68.8$ and $500.4$ are not in the series (they occur "before" the series start) and there are only 12 terms of $S_n$ that are positive.

On the other hand arithmetic and geometric sequences can be extended infinitely in either direction and the "starting point" is utterly arbitrary.  So if we consider sequences indexed by the Integers rather than the Natural this is not an issue.

Nor is it an issue if $a$ and $d$ are both positive or both negative.  Then $k > 0$ and $j > 0$.  But if the are different parity we may find in solving $j$ and $k$ that $a-m$ is that the first of the series but that last or possibly middle term.

===old answer ===

The three terms of an aritmetic sequence are $a; a + d;a+2d$ and the three terms of a geometric sequence are $a; a*r; a*r^2$

So $a = a$

$a+d = a*r$

$a + 2d = a*r^2$.

Subtract the second from the third and you get:

$(a +2d) - (a + d) = a*r^2 - a*r$

$d = a*r(r-1)$.

Subtract the first from the second and get:

$(a + d) - a = ar - a$

$d = a*(r-1)$

So $d = a*r(r-1)= a*(r-1)$

So either $a = 0$, $r-1 = 0$  or $r= 1$ (which is the same as $r-1 = 0$).  In any case:  $d = 0$.

So the sequence is $a, a,a,a.....$.  A constant sequence.

Only a constant sequence is both arithmetic and geometric.

Which makes perfect sense.  If $a \ne 0$ and $r \ne 1$ then $b_2 - b_1 = r*b_1 - r*b_0 = r(b_1 - b_0)\ne b_1 + b_0$.  So if a non-constant geometric sequence can never be arithmetic.

Likewise if $d \ne  0$ then $\frac {b_{i+1}}{b_{i}} \ne \frac {b_{i+1} + d}{b_i + d} = \frac {b_{i+2}}{b_{i+1}}$ if $d\ne 0; b_i \ne b_{i+1}$ (and presumably $b_i:b_{i+1} \ne 0$).

So a nonconstant arithmetic sequence can't be geometric.

Comment: I guess we made the same error thinking **all** the sequence should be both arithmetic and geometric

Comment: The question since  I've answered has been completely edited and altered beyond all recognition.    The orginal was indeed a question about a sequence that was both arithmetic and geometric and my and your answer applies.